# Obtener valor custom list

Tags: java, android

Buenas tardes, estoy trabajando con una custom list, cuya definición es la siguiente (CustomList.java) :

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] Keys, Values;
//private final Integer[] imageId;

public CustomList(Activity context, String[] keys, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, keys);
    this.context = context;
    this.Keys = keys;
    this.Values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtKeys = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.key);
    EditText txtValues = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.value);

    txtKeys.setText(Keys[position]);
    txtValues.setText(Values[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```

El layout de la lista es (list.xml):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/key"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

</TableRow>
```

El segundo objeto lo he definido como EditText ya que mi intención es poder modificar dichos valores y, posteriormente, almacenarlo.

El problema que tengo es que no llego a conseguir almacenar dichos valores ya que, aunque me cree un método en la clase CustomList.java, los valores que tengo en el array son los obtenidos al inicio de la ejecución de la aplicación, por lo que los valores que me almacena son los antiguos y no los nuevos.

¿Alguna solución para poder hacer esto de forma correcta?

P.D. No se si me he expresado bien. Cualquier duda, intentaré explicarla mejor.

Comment: que quieres hacer o que hace la app? es necesario el uso de un customlist?

Comment: El objetivo es, usando firebase, obtener datos de la base de datos de este y mostrarlos en una lista.
El usar un CustomList es para poder usar dos tipos de campos. Uno de ellos es un TextView, que es una etiqueta y, otro campo, que es un editText, en el cual muestro los datos de la base de datos de firebase y que pueden ser modificados.
No se si habría una forma más facil de hacer esto que usando una custom list.
Si que me gustaría mostrarlos en formato lista. Por eso decidí usar esta lista.